# Removing the bottom Padding from a TextView while using HTML Format

Tags: android, html

I try set my html text on `TextView` like this

```
my_text.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml("<p>This is the awesome place to gain</p><p><strong>awesomeness </strong>and <em>deliciuosness. </em>very<em> </em><u>nice</u></p>", HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_PARAGRAPH))
```

I try set the `TextView` with a border, And I got padding bottom like this.

[image]

How to remove that? Because My `TextView` doesn't set anything

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border_black_fill_white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This extra space that you see is infact line break followed by another line break.

When you dive into the Html.fromHtml(...) implementation which is used internally by HtmlCompat.fromHtml, you'll come across the following method that handles paragraph tags:

```
private static void handleP(SpannableStringBuilder text) {
    int len = text.length();

    if (len >= 1 && text.charAt(len - 1) == '\n') {
        if (len >= 2 && text.charAt(len - 2) == '\n') {
            return;
        }

        text.append("\n");
        return;
    }

    if (len != 0) {
        text.append("\n\n");
    }
}
```

So to handle this just trim the string so space added at the end gets removed.

```
 String html = "<p>This is the awesome place to gain</p><p><strong>awesomeness </strong>and <em>deliciuosness. </em>very<em> </em><u>nice</u></p>"

CharSequence trimmedString = trim(Html.fromHtml(html));
myText.setText(trimmedString);

public static CharSequence trim(CharSequence s) {
        int start = 0;
        int end = s.length();
        while (start < end && Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(start))) {
            start++;
        }

        while (end > start && Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(end - 1))) {
            end--;
        }

        return s.subSequence(start, end);
    }
```

This will give you the desired result.

[image]

Comment: Remove `toString()`, and just using `trim()` because use toString, make html format will broken.

Comment: Html.fromHtml returns a Spanned, which can't be trimmed like a String or CharSequence. Will be updating the answer in a while.

Comment: I think it's okay while return `Spanned` because the `TextView` can handle that/

Comment: You are right, textview can handle spanned but to trim the trailing spaces you have to write a custom function which i have written above.

Answer (score 10):

In **kotlin** it's just using `trim()` method:

```
val stringHtml = "<p>This is the awesome place to gain</p><p><strong>awesomeness </strong>and <em>deliciuosness. </em>very<em> </em><u>nice</u></p>"

val spannedHtml = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    Html.fromHtml(stringHtml, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
} else {
    Html.fromHtml(stringHtml)
}

my_text.text = spannedHtml.trim()
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, all existing answers turn the `Spanned` into a regular string, which removes the additional information in the `Spanned`. This Kotlin code is preserving the `Spanned` structure (including links):

```kotlin
fun Spanned.trim() {
    if (this is SpannableStringBuilder) {
        while (length > 0 && this[length-1].isWhitespace()) {
            delete(length-1, length)
        }
        while (length > 0 && this[0].isWhitespace()) {
            delete(0, 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```kotlin
val html = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(rawContent, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
html.trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check once if you have given any bottom padding to TextView in the html file which is set as a background .
Try below code as well..

```
String strHtml = "<br>This is the awesome place to gain</br><br><strong>awesomeness </strong>and <em>deliciuosness. </em>very<em> </em><u>nice</u></br>";

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
  my_text.setText(Html.fromHtml(strHtml, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
} else { 
  my_text.setText(Html.fromHtml(strHtml));
}
```

Comment: Background just making we know that the `TextView` have padding botton.
even do remove the background, `TextView` still have padding bottom