# How do I center html text horizontally and vertically in android TextView

Tags: android, html, css

Here is my TextView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:text="5666" />
</LinearLayout>
```

here is html text:

```
private static final String HTML_CONETNT = "<p>centered text example</p>\n";
```

and here is how I set html content into textview:

```
mTv.setText(Html.fromHtml(HTML_CONETNT));
```

But it‘s just centered horizontally. How do I make it vertically centered?

I've tried css style:

```
    private static final String HTML_CONETNT = "<p style=\"text-align: center\">centered text example</p>\n";
```

but not work as expected.

Comment: Is it possible for you to give hight & width as wrap_context?

Comment: Giving height & width as wrap_content did't help solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the trim method that is written on below link.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56125421

```
String html = "<p>This is the awesome place to gain</p><p><strong>awesomeness </strong>and <em>deliciuosness. </em>very<em> </em><u>nice</u></p>"

CharSequence trimmedString = trim(Html.fromHtml(html));
myText.setText(trimmedString);

public static CharSequence trim(CharSequence s) {
        int start = 0;
        int end = s.length();
        while (start < end && Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(start))) {
            start++;
        }

        while (end > start && Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(end - 1))) {
            end--;
        }

        return s.subSequence(start, end);
    }
```

Comment: It's helpful, thank you! By the way, do you know why android / java add '\n\n' at the end of   <p> tag?  Is it ok to remove the two '\n' ?

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal | center_vertical"
```